# elastic search where clause with constant rank?How to do this?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search. How to generate elastic search equivalent query for 
select * from response where `pnrno='sampleid'`

I know we have to use 'filter' option in elastic search.but we do not need any ranking. (ranking can be constant) so how can I generate query for achieve this

Answer (score 0):

you are correct , you can use filtered query with query clause empty and filters.Filtering a set of documents is to filter the sets upon which query acts to furthur filter/match and calculate relevance.Filters are like bool either match or reject(1/0).

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "FIELD": "VALUE"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of achieving this is by using the [`constant_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) with an embedded [`term` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "pnrno": "sampleid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```